# OR queries in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build a message system. I am planning on having a collections of messages and then querying messages based on sender and receivers. In order to do so I need to query for example: all messages that are sent by Bob and received by Tony and all messages that were sent by Tony and received by Bob. 
I am quite unclear about how to do this "or" statement. 
As of now I have

```
MessageRef.once('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
  console.log(dataSnapshot.val());
});
```

which return all messages. I could then do a forEach but it seems not very efficient. Would you guys have any suggestions?

Also, do you have thoughts on wether my model to build that message system is good vs having chat rooms for example.

Thank you

Comment: Please mention the SQL you already tried to execute

Comment: @CedricSimon: Firebase is not a SQL database.

Comment: My bad. Did read Firebird instead of Firebase ;)

Comment: This sounds like a problem best resolved with a better data structure (i.e. storing the messages in an appropriate structure so there is no need to query by user, et al). See "Firechat":https://firechat.firebaseapp.com/ and "Firefeed":https://firefeed.io/ for examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firebase currently can only query on a single child property. So if you want to query multiple properties, you'll have to combine them into one:

```
Messages
  -DFHJ3498ua
    from: Tony
    to: Bob
    from_to: Tony_Bob
    message: "Hello Bob, this is Tony"
  -DFHJ3598uz
    from: Bob
    to: Tony
    from_to: Bob_Tony
    message: "Hello Tony, What can I do for you?"
  -EFHJ3498ua
    from: Tony
    to: Bob
    from_to: Tony_Bob
    message: "Can you help me with this Firebase query?"
```

You can then query for messages from Bob to Tony using:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://your.firebaseio.com/Messages');
var query = ref.orderByChild('from_to').equalTo('Bob_Tony');
query.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val()); // all messages from Bob to Tony
});
```

In a chat-like application, you might want to consider actually using the sender-receiver pair as the key:

```
Messages
  from_Bob_to_Tony
    -DFHJ3598uz
      from: Bob
      to: Tony
      message: "Hello Tony, What can I do for you?"
  from_Tony_to_Bob
    -DFHJ3498ua
      from: Tony
      to: Bob
      message: "Hello Bob, this is Tony"
    -EFHJ3498ua
      from: Tony
      to: Bob
      message: "Can you help me with this Firebase query?"
```

With this data structure you won't have to run a query to get the relevant messages, but can do a direct lookup.

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://your.firebaseio.com/Messages');
var query = ref.child('from_Bob_to_Tony');
query.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val()); // all messages from Bob to Tony
});
```

Comment: Thanks :) Quick questions: if I do sender-receiver pair I would need to do 2 queries ( from T to B and B to T), combine them and sort them by time. Should I not then organize it by rooms of people?

Comment: Also if I do a room system, should I have a room collection where each item has a long array of message or I should create a message collection that references to the room? What is the best schema?

Comment: Your question said "messages that were sent by Tony and received by Bob", so that's what I modeled in my answer. If you want messages **between** Tony and Bob, you can model for that, e.g. by ordering the name before putting them in the key. So a key like "messages_between_Bob_and_Tony".

Comment: If you want to model chat rooms, model chat rooms. If you want rooms between participants to be persistent (so when the same people start talking again, they see their previous messages), that'll be easiest if you model based on user-names/IDs. But all of this is incredibly broad and it is impossible to determine the "best" answer for you without going over all of your use-cases, for which StackOverflow is not the forum. Just start with what seems right and adapt to new insights. Or have a look at https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#session/ztbgh3woflv or https://github.com/firebase/firechat

Comment: These are two different fields what if the query is if to is either bob or julie how to do that?