# Firebase writing a Query

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

This is How My Document looks like, I want to write a query in which i want to Display only those roomnames whose UserOne or Usetwo Has my name or any name i want.

```
firebase.database().ref('OnetoOne/').on('value', resp => {
    this.OnetoOne = [];
    this.OnetoOne = snapshotToArray(resp);
    this.isLoadingResults = false;
});
```

Currently i am using this Query to fetch all the roomname.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "Query and not JS"?

Comment: I want to do That just Via firebase Query.

Comment: Have your tried this https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filter_by_key_or_value

Comment: There is no way to do a single query that performs an OR filter on two properties. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034092/or-queries-in-firebase